# I can't create a new server in my pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to create a local server in pgAdmin on a my ubuntu 18.04 but I am getting this error.

this is the error
[image: this is the error]

and here are my settings

[image: Here are my settings]

Comment: So, **do** you have a Postgres server installed on the host 192.168.100.101?

Comment: Or maybe in your server do you already edit in your pg_hba.conf to add connection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solved it, I have tried lot of things, one of them did it, most likely this one:

`sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter user postgres password 'postgres'`

I changed the server IP to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: `sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter user postgres password 'postgres'"  `   -- Very minor correction